# Vue.JS Axios POST request .then method

Tags: post, vue.js, axios

Im stuck!

I'm sending a POST request to a server via AXIOS from a VUE app. 
Everything works and the server responds. 
The problem is, that the .then method never gets called. How could that be?
Bonus question how are you doing your requests from VUE?

Many thanks

```
methods:{
    customMethod1: function() {

        //AXIOS
        var config = {
            headers: {'My Custom Header 1': 'Header-Value'}
        };

        //POST request
        axios.post('http://192.168.56.101:5000/post1', {name: 'Dave'}, config)

        .then(function(response){
            alert("posted successfully");
        });

        },

}
```

Comment: Can u show full code of module? Perhaps, you do not call method

Comment: Thank for your reply Kirill. The method `customMethod1` gets called. The post request gets executed and the server replies. Just `.then` black I can not get to do anything.

Comment: Try adding a `catch` callback, just to be sure it's not failing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed via a tool like Fiddler that the server actually sends a response? It could be that the server never actually responds.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution, and I don't know if I should share it with the person who posted this question : he could at least answer to the others trying to help him.
As I find many answers here I post my solution (maybe not the correct answer but it works)

**It's not a vue.js issue, nor axios**, the .then statement is called only when you return something on server side.

Some code to explain :

```
Product.update(
        {
            productName: req.body.productName,
            productDesc: req.body.productDesc,
            productOwner: 0,
            productImage: req.body.productImage,
            productState: req.body.ProductState,
            productPrice: req.body.ProductPrice
        },
        {
            where: {
                id: req.body.id
            }
        })
        .then(function (item) {
            console.log("Product update " + item.id);
            res.send({id: item.id});    
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Product update error " + err);
        });
```

the important line here is :

```
res.send({id: item.id});
```

If you return nothing at server side your .then at client side is not called.

let me know if it works but +1 me ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, this was a brief test I have done and I don't have the setup to test your answer. However, your answer makes sense in terms of that there has to be a return value to trigger the promise .then. I wish i could delete this question...